# SharePoint List Pre-Population

Tags: sharepoint, list

I have two lists, each on different tabs (sub-sites) of the site. I would like users enter data on the first tab and somehow copy a portion of that data over to the second list automatically (like a pre-population of several of the fields on the second list). What would be involved in making this happen? Of the ideas I have come up with, none seem too pragmatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An item receiver on the first list would allow you to insert data into another list at the time of creation.

Depending on your situation it may be worth trying list look ups (one to many).